# Renaming a file based on existing text in file name using batch scripts only

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

How can I used batch commands to rename a file based upon existing text in name?  For example, if I have a file named:

`abc-pqr123Jan20151321f`

I might need to rename it to

`q~hello~Jan-2015~zz`.

I will always need to use the month and year already present in the file name; it will always be at the same place in the source file name. Other characters in the name can be any random text. Month and year will change for all months.

I'd like to rename just one file at a time. Only batch commands are to be used.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, and we'll help you fix what's broken. Also, what are the restrictions on the input file format?  Will the month always contain the first upper case character of the filename?  Or will it always start at the 11th character?

Comment: Yes It will always start at 11th character. The file name will always be similar to as mentioned above. Month will have first upper case character in file name. I will need to capture those 7 characters and include them in new file name. Restriction is to use only batch scripts. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "FilePath=C:\test\abc-pqr123Jan20151321f"
for %%a in ("%FilePath%\*") do set "FileName=%%~nxa"
set "NewName=q~hello~%FileName:~10,7%~zz"
echo ren "%FilePath%\%FileName%" "%NewName%"
```

Comment: Welcome back to SO Endoro :) .

Comment: Hi, It seems to be helpful. I tested it as per my requirement. I am facing one small issue here. How can I pass the file name at run time which will always be coming in a specified folder, lets say C:/test/abc-pqr123Jan20151321f . The file name will be changing for every month so I would want to pass it at run time, not hard coded. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are there more files in "C:/test/abc-pqr123Jan20151321f" and if yes, what file do you need?

Comment: there would be only one .CSV file . I will have to pass the file name to batch script for renaming. I was reading about using %~x1 but dont know how to use it.

Comment: @endoro I am trying various combinations to pass the file name but no success :( .

Comment: I tried it. It is taking the full path in name i.e starting for C:\ . I just wanted file name present in test folder. here is my code.  @echo on &setlocal disabledelayedexpansion


For %%a IN (C:\Users\John\Desktop\test\*) do Set "Filename= %%~a"


echo %FileName%

if %Filename:~4,2%==pq ( if %Filename:~13,4%==2015 ( Set "NewName=herione"))
if %Filename:~4,2%==04 ( if %Filename:~13,4%==2015 ( Set "NewName=hero"))
if %Filename:~4,2%==05 ( if %Filename:~13,4%==2015 ( Set "NewName=villian"))

CD C:\Users\John\Desktop\test
ren *.* %NewName%.csv

Comment: @Sharma there was a bug with the file path, made an edit again.

Comment: @Endoro i was able to do many of the tasks with ur help. I am stuck at one place again. How can i run the above code for each file in the path. for example if I have 12 files for each month in the test path and I want to rename each file based upon its current  name by doing some comparison. Is that possible. I tried to use /f option before %%a in ur code but it did nt help.

Comment: @Endoro or can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Temp> set f=abc-pqr123Jan20151321f

C:\Temp> set x=q~hello~%f:~10,7%~zz

C:\Temp> echo %x%
q~hello~Jan2015~zz

C:\Temp> _
```

The constraint “Only batch commands are to be used” is a bit unclear and weird. What commands quality as “batch commands”? And why on Earth restrict yourself to those?

If this is **homework**, then please, for future such questions, state in the question that it's homework, because that affects how we best can help you.

Comment: It did not run successfully. Error:  the following usage of path operator in batch parameter substitution is invalid : %~zz. It also says syntax is incorrect set x=q~hello~%f:~10,7%~zz
 .please suggest

Comment: @Sharma: I guess the tilde characters are part of the homework assignment, so I won't say more than that it's fixable. First, try to figure out what the error message means. E.g. try to consistently reproduce that problem with some other code. Of course, for professional work the by far best solution is to just change those problematic characters. So you see, the answers depend very much on whether this is professional or homework.

Comment: I guess you mean it's not working in a batch file, when you have tried some other delimiter. It works just fine here.